# Clustering Pie Charts with Charts.js on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, pie-chart, markerclusterer, chart.js

I am trying to create a cluster map with pie charts using this code below without success.

```
markercluster = L.markerClusterGroup({maxclustersRadius: 2 * rmax //,iconCreateFunction: testcluster } // add a pie chart here with Chart.js
                                     }),
```

As you can see I try to create a custom Chart as testcluster into the iconCreateFunction option.

The testcluster function looks like these:

```
function testcluster(cluster) {

var ctx = document.getElementById("marker-cluster").getContext("2d"),

children = cluster.getAllChildMarkers(),

html = new Chart(ctx).Pie(children,{
//Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
segmentShowStroke : true,
//String - The colour of each segment stroke
segmentStrokeColor : "#fff"
}),
//Create the div

myPieChart = new L.DivIcon({ 

html: html,
className: 'marker-cluster'
} );


return myPieChart;

}
```

What I intend here is to create a summed up pie chart as I zoom out and want to split the data as I zoom in. I've checked the D3 version but found it too complicated and decided doing it with Charts.js. But any workable and easy lib is ok.

I've uploaded the http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728 data but my intention is to do it without the D3.js

jsfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/kuof3L5j/`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to put this in a jsfiddle if you want help.

Comment: The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/kuof3L5j/

Comment: Do you know how to create a jsfiddle? Add the js, css and other resources. Turn on the debugging tools, you'll see that the page can't load the libraries.

Comment: Just updated it, I couldn't make the gejson work, though.